# How Generic Typed Array not allowed in Java (SE8) works?

Tags: java

I was trying to implement an R-way Trie Symbol Table, but meanwhile the implementation I have faced an unusual issue or I was not able to wrap head around this. Let me explain the issue I am facing:

```
package edu.nraj.dsalgo.rwaytrie;

public class RWayTrieST<Value> {
    private static final int R = 256; 
    private Node root = new Node();

    private class Node{
        private Object value;
        private Node[] next = new Node[R];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

}
```

in this code block one can clearly see that I am creating an internal private class

```
private class Node{ ... }
```

But now the java se8 compiler shows an issue for the

```
private Node[] next = new Node[R];
```

saying that `arrays of generic types not allowed. Node` which I already happen to know that Java doesn't allow a generic type array.

[image: The generic type array issue hint screenshot]

But here the compiler stop throwing the error if I make this `Private Node class` a static class.

```
package edu.nraj.dsalgo.rwaytrie;

public class RWayTrieST<Value> {
    private static final int R = 256; 
    private Node root = new Node();

    private static class Node{
        private Object value;
        private Node[] next = new Node[R];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

}
```

[image: No issue after adding static to Node class screenshot]

Can someone please explain this behavior down to its root cause so I can wrap my head around this.

Comment: What if R is not static? Do you get the same behaviour?

Comment: Yes Ankur... i get the same error.

Comment: Ok. Btw you would avoid downvotes if code is not pasted as images.

Comment: Thanks for that downvote advice Ankur.

Comment: No problem I upvoted since the question covers an important concept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make your inner class static, it basically makes `Node` not care about the generic parameter `Value`. If `Node` is not static, `Node` then "belongs to instances of `RWayTrieST`", just like any other non-static member. This means that the `Node` of an instance of `RWayTrieST<String>` will be a different type than the `Node` of an instance of `RWayTrieST<Integer>`.

This is as if `Node` itself has a generic parameter, isn't it? `RWayTrieST<String>.Node` and `RWayTrieST<Integer>.Node` are entirely different types (at compile time, at least), just like `ArrayList<String>` and `ArrayList<Integer>`.

According to [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createArrays), you can't create arrays of type with generic parameters, because something like this could happen if this were allowed:

```
RWayTrieST<String> foo = ...;
RWayTrieST<Integer> bar = ...;
Object[] stringArray = foo.new Node<String>[];  // compiler error, but pretend it's allowed
stringArray[0] = foo.new Node<String>();   // OK
stringArray[1] = bar.new Node<Integer>();  // An ArrayStoreException should be thrown,
                                            // but the runtime can't detect it, because generic types are erased.
```

Comment: okay, now I get it, after relating `RWayTrieST<String>.Node` with `Cannot create a generic array of RWayTrieST<Value>.Node` .

Comment: @NeerajKumar Please consider accepting the answer that you think is the best by clicking on that checkmark!

Answer (score 1):

In the simplest way I can put this, when you make a class generic, all its inner classes are also generic because they share the outer class information. As you probably already know, the difference between

```
public class RWayTrieST<Value> {
    private class Node {}
}
```

and

```
public class RWayTrieST<Value> {
    private static class Node {}
}
```

is that, in the former, Node is an inner class and instances of `Node` have to be tied to instances of `RWayTrieST`. So if you have `foo = New RWayTrieST<String>()` and you have `bar = foo.new Node()`, then to the compiler, `bar`'s type is effectively `RWayTrieST<String>.Node` because the generic information of the outer class is necessary.

In the latter however, instances of `Node` are not tied to instances of `RWayTrieST` because it is a static inner class. So `Node` does not share the outer class generic info which means it is not generic.

Comment: Can you explain? How the error in first case and not the second case and why that specific error is coming ? Does this mean that the compiler is forcibly making the array as a generic type array?

Comment: The error is `arrays of generic types not allowed`. I explained that in the first case Node is a generic type because it is an inner class of a generic class, and in the second case it is not generic, so no error. I thought that was clear enough.

Comment: Got it! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, @Lee Aso that makes sense. But don't you think it shouldn't be this way, isn't it the shortcoming kinda thing...

Comment: Looked like it to me as well @NeerajKumar , but then there probably has to be way to say that generic type should not be propagated i.e. explicitly . Probably that will make it too complicated?

Answer (score 0):

If think the reason lies in the hidden details:

```
public class RWayTrieST<Value> {
    private static final int R = 256; 
    private Node root = new Node();    
    private class Node{
        private Object value;
        private Node[] next = new Node[R];
    }   
}
```

Is actually:

```
public class RWayTrieST<Value> {
    private static final int R = 256; 
    private Node root = new Node();    
    private class Node<Value>{
        private final RWayTrieST<Value> $PARENT;
        private Object value;
        private Node[] next = new Node[R]; // and so Node is Node<Value> by this.
    }   
}
```

`$PARENT` is a synthetic field (although that's not the exact name) the compiler adds to allow call to the parent non static methods. If the parent class contains generics, then the type of the `$PARENT` is the `RWayTrieST<Value>`.

And since Value is from the class declaration, it needs to be passed down to instance as well:

```
private static class Node<Value>
```

And so on in declaration, hence `new Node<Value>[R]`.

If you want to fix that:

- If you don't need to call the parent' non static methods, then use `static class` as you were doing.
- Use a `ArrayList`.
- If you need to call parent static method, then make the `Node` class `static` and add a private field `RWayTrieST<?>`. You will probably have other problems.

Comment: Suggested an edit. Class shouldn’t have static in the “is actually” right?

Comment: As you wish. All that matter is the hidden field after all :)